# like statement not returning full text

Tags: mysql

I am running a like statement from a mediumtext column (data) trying to extract certain data and replace with text;

```
 Select
 CASE  WHEN data like '%CPCCCA2002B - Use carpentry tools and equipment:["Workplace Based Training With Employer"]%' THEN 'Workplace' else 0 end as Option

  FROM formz.user z
```

But is seems that the query will not look for anything past 'equipment'
I would greatly appreciate some help with this.

Comment: Is there a newline after "...equipment:", by any chance?

Comment: Are you saying it matches text that does not contain the part after "equipment"? Can you show an example of a record that matches even though it should not (or the other way around)?

Comment: That's because square brackets mean "character class" in a LIKE argument, like in regexps. You'd need to escape them. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pattern-matching.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If above given is your real sample data then after placing `backtick` to the alias name whereas it was considering as a `keyword`

```
CREATE TABLE testing(content VARCHAR(1000))

INSERT INTO testing VALUES 
('Another things CPCCCA2002B - Use carpentry tools and equipment:["Workplace Based Training With Employer"]testing')

SELECT
 CASE WHEN content 
    LIKE '%CPCCCA2002B - Use carpentry tools and equipment:["Workplace Based Training With Employer"]%' 
THEN 'Workplace' ELSE 0 END AS `Option`
FROM testing z
```

And if it's giving issue due to `[` then use any special character before it like `*[` then use below syntax

```
CASE WHEN content LIKE 'sfsdf*[dsfad' ESCAPE '*' THEN 'Workplace' ELSE '' END
```

Note: As i tried it, I didn't find second issue but in case if it's the problem then you can get rid of that using above syntax but use the character which never comes in your real content.

**OUTPUT:**

```
Option
---------
Workplace
```